# How do I get yason:encode-alist to return the encoded string instead of sending it to a stream?

Tags: json, encoding, stream, common-lisp

I'm trying to encode a JSON string from an alist using YASON. The problem is, the return value I'm getting is the original alist I fed it. It's printing the JSON string, and according to [the documentation](http://hanshuebner.github.io/yason/#encoding), it goes to `*STANDARD-OUTPUT*`.

Simple example session:

```
(ql:quickload :yason)
To load "yason":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    yason
; Loading "yason"

(:YASON)
* (defparameter starving-json-eater (yason:encode-alist '(("foo" . "bar") ("baz" . "qux"))))
{"foo":"bar","baz":"qux"}
STARVING-JSON-EATER
* starving-json-eater

(("foo" . "bar") ("baz" . "qux"))
```

I've tried passing `'starving-json-eater` into the `stream` parameter, but I get an error:

```
* (setf starving-json-eater (yason:encode-alist '(("foo" . "bar") ("baz" . "qux")) 'starving-json-eater))

debugger invoked on a SIMPLE-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {1001E06783}>:
  There is no applicable method for the generic function
    #<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION SB-GRAY:STREAM-WRITE-CHAR (1)>
  when called with arguments
    (STARVING-JSON-EATER #\{).

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [RETRY] Retry calling the generic function.
  1: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

((:METHOD NO-APPLICABLE-METHOD (T)) #<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION SB-GRAY:STREAM-WRITE-CHAR (1)> STARVING-JSON-EATER #\{) [fast-method]
```

How can I get `{"foo":"bar","baz":"qux"}` into `starving-json-eater`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`WITH-OUTPUT-TO-STRING`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_w_out_.htm) to temporarily bind a variable to an open stream which writes into a string. You may even bind the special variable `*standard-output*` so that you only change the dynamic context of your code without providing explicitly a different stream argument (like when you redirect streams with processes).

```
(with-output-to-string (*standard-output*)
  (yason:encode-alist '(("a" . "b"))))
```

Note that binding `*standard-output*` means that anything that writes to `*standard-output*` will end up being written in the string during the extent of `with-output-to-string`. In the above case, the scope is sufficiently limited to avoid unexpectedly capturing output from nested code. You could also use a lexical variable to control precisely who gets to write to the string:

```
(with-output-to-string (json)
  (yason:encode-alist '(("a" . "b")) json))
```

Comment: Better than my answer! Thanks! :)

Comment: @ClaireNielsen Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to create a throwaway string output stream to catch the value, and then grab it from later:

```
* (ql:quickload :yason)
To load "yason":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    yason
; Loading "yason"

(:YASON)
* (defparameter sated-json-eater (make-string-output-stream))

SATED-JSON-EATER
* (yason:encode-alist '(("foo" . "bar") ("baz" . "qux")) sated-json-eater)

(("foo" . "bar") ("baz" . "qux"))
* (defparameter json-string (get-output-stream-string sated-json-eater))

JSON-STRING
* json-string

"{\"foo\":\"bar\",\"baz\":\"qux\"}"
```

This can be hidden away in a function:

```
(defun json-string-encode-alist (alist-to-encode)
  (let ((stream (make-string-output-stream)))
    (yason:encode-alist alist-to-encode stream)
    (get-output-stream-string stream)))
```

Comment: You can also use the macro [`WITH-OUTPUT-TO-STRING`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_w_out_.htm) instead of calling `MAKE-STRING-OUTPUT-STREAM` and `GET-OUTPUT-STREAM-STRING` directly.